# Maven - scope of the aws-java-sdk dependency

Tags: maven, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

When developing on AWS what should be the scope of the aws-java-sdk dependency?
I see the war file created exceeds 60MB so I was wondering if I will not package all the sdk jars will tomcat on AWS provide all the dependency?

```
<dependency>
<groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
<artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
<version>1.11.106</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> if I will not package all the sdk jars will tomcat on AWS provide all
>   the dependency?

No Tomcat running on AWS will not automatically provide the AWS SDK dependencies for you. However you don't have to include the entire SDK. You can include only the individual SDK modules that correspond to the AWS services you want your code to interact with. For example to only include the S3 module, you would use the following:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
   <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-s3</artifactId>
   <version>1.11.106</version>
</dependency>
```

See the **Specifying individual SDK modules** section in [the documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/setup-project-maven.html) for more details.